# Extract a string in R

Tags: r, string

I have the following vector

```
v <- c("feasible", "URE.feasible","RE.β0","RE.β1","RE.β2","URE.β0","URE.β1","URE.β2","URE.SE.β0","URE.SE.β1","URE.SE.β2")
```

I would like to extract only `c("URE.β0","URE.β1","URE.β2")` so I coded this

```
which(grepl("URE.", v))
```

but i got more. How can I only get the this   `c("URE.β0","URE.β1","URE.β2")`?

Comment: You can add the start (`^`) and end (`$`) to make sure it won't match more characters `grep("^URE\\...$", v, value = TRUE)`  If we have only betas to match `grep("^URE\\.β[0-9]+", v, value = TRUE)`

Comment: Did you try `which(grepl("URE.β", v))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
grep("^URE\\.β[0-9]+", v)
```

This will give you indices of the matches:

```
[1] 6 7 8
```

If you want values:

```
grep("^URE\\.β[0-9]+", v, value=TRUE)
```

This produces:

```
[1] "URE.β0" "URE.β1" "URE.β2"
```

With use of `grep` instead of `grepl`, you won't need the "which" call. The '^' ensures that only strings beginning with 'URE' are matched, since '^' matches the beginning of a string or a line being matched. Leave out the '+' if only one digit after 'β' needs to be matched.